# How to get last inserted 10 records in descending order using dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am new in amazone-dynamodb. I want  last inserted 10 records in descending order using dynamodb.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your table? Otherwise it is difficult to help you. Anyways, here is a very simple Geeting Started on how to query dynamodb with nodejs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html

Comment: Lets one table named Movies. There is year – The partition key  and title – The sort key. I want last inserted 10 records in descending order. So what will query if i have no partition key value and sort key value.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB allows to sort the data only by `sort key` attribute. The `ScanIndexForward` option can be used to sort the data in ascending or descending order.

Please note that the ordering will be done for the specific partition key only. It will not sort all the items in the table and give you the last 10 records. The sort operation can be done for the specific partition key.

> ScanIndexForward
>
> Specifies the order for index traversal: If true (default), the
>   traversal is performed in ascending order; if false, the traversal is
>   performed in descending order.

**Sort key definition and example:-**

> A composite partition-sort key is indexed as a partition key element
>   and a sort key element. This multi-part key maintains a hierarchy
>   between the first and second element values. For example, a composite
>   partition-sort key could be a combination of “UserID” (partition) and
>   “Timestamp” (sort). Holding the partition key element constant, you
>   can search across the sort key element to retrieve items. This would
>   allow you to use the Query API to, for example, retrieve all items for
>   a single UserID across a range of timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using the DynamoDB example here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.01.html

The sample data does not have insertion timestamps.

Another catch is, that you can only sort at DynamoDB by using the Sort Key, otherwise you need to perform the sorting in code.

So if your Partition Key is the Year, and the Sort Key is the Title, you need to:

1. Introduce an attribute which provides you with a timestamp of creation.
2. Create the table with an [LSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) of this attribute, or create a [GSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) using the new attribute as your Sort Key.
3. Now you can use query!

The Query API has an option to:

- Sort by the Sort Key in descending order (using ScanIndexForward parameter)
- Limiting the number of items returned (using Limit parameter)

Comment: I don't want to use GSI. If i use timestamp attribute as sort key then is it possible to get record in descending order?

Comment: Yes that is possible. Use the Query API, and take a look at the ScanIndexForward parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Abhaya Chauhan is mostly correct, though there is one inaccuracy. The Limit parameter does not actually limit the number of items returned, but rather limit the number of items scanned (irregardless of whether they match the search criteria).

Thus if you set a Limit of 10, you might get anywhere between 0 and 10 items. See the below docs for more info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Limit